# Spark Accumulator vs Count

Tags: apache-spark

I have a use case where I want to count types of elements in an RDD matching some filter.

e.g. RDD.filter(F1) and RDD.filter(!F1)

I have 2 options

1. Use accumulators: e.g.

> ```
> LongAccumulator l1 = sparkContext.longAccumulator("Count1")
> LongAccumulator l2 = sparkContext.longAccumulator("Count2")
> RDD.forEachPartition(f -> {
>     if(F1) l1.add(1)
>     else l2.add(1)
> });
> ```

2. Use Count

> `RDD.filter(F1).count(); RDD.filter(!F1).count()`

One benefit of the first approach is that we only need to iterate data once (useful since my data set is 10s of TB)

What is the use of count if same affect can be achieved by using Accumulators ?

Comment: Did you find any reasonable answer to this question?

Answer (score 3):

Major difference is that if your code will fail in transformation, then Accumulators will be [updated](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/scheduler/DAGScheduler.scala#L1318) and count() result not.

Other option is to use pure map-reduce:

```
val counts = rdd.map(x => (F1(x), 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _).collectAsMap()
```

Network cost should be also low as only few numbers will be sent. It creates pairs of (is F1(x) true/false, 1) and then sum all ones - it will give you number of items both F1(x) and !F1(x) in counts map

Comment: The problem you mentioned only exist if Accumulators are updated in transformation, in the example above, the update is being made in action.

Comment: @user401445 You are right - my mistake. But I will recommend second code - it can "survive" failures and you don't need to worry if you are in action or transformation